# Worldbuilding Materials

Tags: worldbuilding-process, worldbuilding-resources

**When you create a religion, organization, or any other object within your world, can related materials be useful for realizing the world?**

For example:
If you create a religion, will an excerpt of a prayer help define the religion?
If you create an organization, will an internal document or a meeting conclusion document help learn more about it?
If you create a location, will an excerpt from a tourist guide help define it better?

Comment: I think this could be a very good question with a bit of rephrasing, but at the moment it’s pretty much the definition of opinion based. There’s no way to judge the ‘rightness’ of an answer as ‘yes’ and ‘no’ are both valid responses. Perhaps rephrasing to be more about the usefulness of such assets rather than ‘do you make these things’ might help? I’m going to VTC, but bear in mind on hold questions get re-opened if they’re edited to meet the site criteria detailed in the help centre!

Comment: @JoeBloggs I have edited to focus on usefulness. I may still need to rephrase this better. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Interesting question. Are you asking about producing the fictional versions of these documents, or incorporating real-world documents into your worldbuilding? Either way I'd say yes, but it would change the answer a bit :)

Comment: @Ynneadwraith Producing the fictional versions of these documents. But incorporating real-world documents sounds interesting as well!

Comment: Also, how important this religion/organization/location is to your story? I mean, if the religion can explain how your character behave, it's good to understand this religion in depth, but if it's just a background cultural thing without real consequences, it's less important

Comment: @Kepotx some are encountered directly during the story, some are existing in the background and influence the behavior of some people the characters meet in the world. For my records' completeness, I would invest equally in both background and foreground aspects of the world.

Comment: I had written a set of guidelines to help you know when to put the extra effort and when not, but with the question on hold, I cannot post it. Sorry

Comment: Are you able to vote against something being closed as opinion-based? I'd argue that the answer to all of these questions is unequivocally yes (provided there are no time constraints), but the visibility of these should be dependent on the media.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a matter of compromise. Giving details can be good, but be wary to don't bore your reader.
A good compromise could be to expose such (short) document in the middle of the story, and add some less important document, more related to the background, in the appendix of the book.
A common document put in appendix of fantasy books is the universe map : one can see such document at any moment to understand the world better, but it's optional, so it doesn't necessarily slow the reading.